# To change the size of Dropdown Text box

Tags: html, css, angular

I have to increase the size of the dropdown.
HTML

```html
<div *ngIf="SecondView">
  <span class="search-view">
      <input class="form-check-input position-static push-down-3" 
          name="custView" type="radio" value="branchView" 
          aria-label="..." (click)="View(2)">
      Branch View
  </span>
  <label>
    <div class="changes" *ngIf="showBranchDropdown">
      <ng-select placeholder="All" [virtualScroll]="true" 
          formControlName="assignBranchName">
          <ng-option *ngFor="let data of assignBranchData" [value]="data.id">
          {{data.name}}
          </ng-option>
      </ng-select>
    </div>
  </label>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.changes{
width:200px;
}
```

This is the current dropdown size:

[image: Image a]

It should be like this:

[image: Image b]

Answer (score 1):

try `min-width` in place of `width`

```
.changes{
   min-width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the name of your placeholder.

Comment: Read this: [answer]